# Jquery Mobile dialog box doesn't fire Backspace for input type text

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, dialog

I have a form for Jquery mobile dialog box. When I enter something in the input type text field and press backspace. The event doesn't fire. Any ideas what could be the reason?

Comment: with the limited information you have in your question it will be difficult to help. Can you please add the Code you are using, the device and browser, and the JQM version. could you also create a jsfiddle demo that shows exactly this problem, and post a link to this demo in you question?

Comment: No thank you I have solved it! It was a Keydown event clashing with my backspace event in the dialog box. Thanks Anyways!